# Comparing two post_ids in WordPress always returns true

Tags: wordpress

Ok, I'm adding a select menu to my meta box, and I want to list other pages of the same post type except for the page we're on. Here's the code:

```
<select id="page_redirect_select">
<option value="">Select a Page</option>
<?php   
$this_id = $post->ID;
$args = array('post_type' => 'custom-post', 'nopaging'  => true);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $query_id = $query->post->ID;
        if($this_id !== $query_id){
            echo "<option value='";
            echo the_permalink();
            echo "'>".get_the_title();
            echo "</option>\n";
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
<option value="other">Other URL</option>
</select>
```

Now, when I echo $this_id, I get 94. $query_id is equal to 6. However, in the comparison of ($this_id !== $query_id) it returns true! Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you are saying "if `$this_id` is not equal to `$query_id`" and that condition indeed is fulfilled here, no?

Comment: i am agree with @Pekka in simple term 94 is not equal to 6 statement is true

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I had another wp_query before this, and wp_reset_postdata wasn't working!
So it was carrying over the post ID from the last query I ran.

Note: wp_reset_postdata DOES NOT work! Instead, you'll need to do this:
    $old_post = $post;
    //...
    //do wp_query work
    //...
    $post = $old_post;
I wonder if the WordPress guys know this...